# Create a Dataframe from list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have two list of lists which looks like the following

```
ingre_list = [['chicken',
'oil',
  'garlic',
  'pepper',
  'juice',
  'sugar',
  'ketchup',
  'vinegar',
  'water',
  'sauce'],
 ['butter', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'bananas', 'salt'],
 ['pork',
  'beef',
  'egg',
  'cheese',
  'bread',
  'garlic',
  'salt',
  'pepper',
  'milk',
  'parsley'],
 ['beef',
  'bread',
  'egg',
  'onions',
  'salt',
  'pepper',
  'ketchup',
  'milk',
  'vinegar',
  'sugar',
  'ketchup'],
 ['salt', 'sugar', 'butter'],
 ['sausage',
  'garlic',
  'tomatoes',
  'sauce',
  'water',
  'basil',
  'parsley',
  'sugar',
  'salt',
  'pepper',
  'pepper',
  'spaghetti',
  'cheese'],
 ['bananas',
  'juice',
  'salt',
  'butter',
  'sugar',
  'eggs',
  'butter',
  'cheese',
  'cream',
  'sugar'],
 ['beef', 'gravy', 'dressing', 'dressing', 'water'],
 ['salt', 'butter', 'sugar', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'oats', 'raisins']]

 quan_list= [['2 lbs',
  '2',
  '2',
  '3/4 teaspoon',
  '1/4 cup',
  '1/3 cup',
  '2 tablespoons',
  '1 tablespoon',
  '1/2 cup',
  '1/3 cup'],
 ['1/2 cup', '1 cup', '1', '1', '1/2 teaspoon'],
 ['1/2',
  '1/2',
  '1/2',
  '1/2 cup',
  '1/3 cup',
  '1/3',
  '1/3',
  '1 teaspoon',
  '1/3 cup',
  '1/4 cup'],
 ['1/4',
  '1/4',
  '1/4',
  '1/4',
  '1 teaspoon',
  '1/4 teaspoon',
  '4 tablespoons',
  '1/2-2/3 cup',
  '4 tablespoons',
  '4',
  '1/2 cup'],
 ['1 teaspoon', '1/4 cup', '1/2 cup'],
 ['2 lbs',
  '2',
  '2',
  '2',
  '2 cups',
  '3 teaspoons',
  '2 teaspoons',
  '2',
  '1 teaspoon',
  '1/4-1/2 teaspoon',
  '1/4 teaspoon',
  '1/4',
  '1/4'],
 ['1/4',
  '2 teaspoons',
  '1/4 teaspoon',
  '3/4 cup',
  '3/4',
  '3/4',
  '1/2 cup',
  '1/2',
  '1/2',
  '1/2'],
 ['1/2', '1/2', '1/2', '1/2', '1/2 cup'],
 ['1 teaspoon', '1 cup', '1 cup', '1 cup', '1', '3 cups', '3']]
```

The `quan_list` and `ingre_list` are of same length. Each inner list of both the lists are of same length. For example `quan_list[0]` has the same size as that of `ingre_list[0]`. I want to create a dataframe from these lists with the headers be the items from the `ingre_list` and each item should appear once in the header. Then each row should contain the quantity of the ingredient from the `quan_list`. 
To create the empty dataframe I have used the following code:

```
unique_ingre= set(x for l in ingre_list for x in l)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=unique_ingre)
```

Now I am having trouble to insert the quantities in each row.

Example Dataframe consider the values `ingre_list[0]` and `quan_list[0]`

```
bread egg chicken   sugar      dressing ..... water    garlic
           2 lbs   1/3 cup                    1/2 cup      2
```

IF anyone can please help me its really appreciated. Just to let you know that length of quan_list and ingre_list can increase. Its also fine if this thing can be written in a csv file in python.

Comment: This is not true in your sample *Each inner list of both the lists are of same length. For example quan_list[0] has the same size as that of ingre_list[0]*

Comment: The elements somehow got swapped. I will edit it.

Comment: @YOBEN_S Ihave made the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try , notice I am adding `groupby` and `head` due to your `ingre_list` have duplicated item within each sub-list, if in real data there is no duplicates , you can remove `.groupby(level=0).head(1)`

```
s=pd.concat([pd.Series(y, index=x).groupby(level=0).head(1) for x , y in zip(ingre_list , quan_list)],axis=1).T
```

Comment: Alright that worked thank you so much. I do have duplicated items in my real list. The list I provided is just of length 10 whereas the total length is 176000. I need to understand how that comprehension code worked. Than you so much